# How to match sequences of boolean values in a data.frame column?

Tags: r, boolean, pattern-matching

I need to match a specific sequence of boolean values in a column, like the 'sample'-vector below.  In this case, I'm interested to know whether there is any occurrence of the pattern in the column.

However, my code seems to ignore the explicit pattern in my sample vector and instead returns True if it can find any item from the sample vector in the column. In this case, only the column test1 should evaluate to True.

How can I match the pattern in a correct way?

```
sample <- rep(TRUE, 3)
df <- data.frame(test1 = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 3),
                 test2 = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), 3),
                 test3 = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 3))

> lapply(1:ncol(df), FUN=function(i){any(sample %in% df[,i])})
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I can imagine this being a duplicate, however, all I could find on SO were regex type of solutions, rather than matching the sequence of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution.

I must admit that **the function is not mine**, I saw it somewhere a long time ago and have not written in the .R file where I found it, so I cannot give the credits.

But it does what is asked for, to find a given sub-sequence of a vector. The data is recreated because in the question the data.frame has two `test2` and because `sample` is a base function. I have changed both.

```
occurs <- function(x, y) {
  m <- length(x)
  n <- length(y)
  candidate <- seq.int(length = n - m + 1L)
  for (i in seq.int(length = m)) {
    candidate <- candidate[x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]]
  }
  candidate
}

x <- rep(TRUE, 3)
df1 <- data.frame(test1 = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 3),
                  test2 = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), 3),
                  test3 = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 3))

occurs(x, df1$test1)
#[1] 3 7

lapply(df1, \(y) occurs(x, y))
#$test1
#[1] 3 7
#
#$test2
#integer(0)
#
#$test3
#integer(0)
```

The sequence is present twice in `test1` at positions 3 and 7 and not present in the other columns.

---

### Edit

A run of `occurs` with only the first `df1` column, renamed `y`.
The algorithm is to have a moving window into `y`, and to match it to the sequence in `x`.
The reassignment of `candidate` each iteration through the loop will keep shortening the `candidate` vector. In the end only the sequence of elements of `y` that match all elements of `x` will still be in `candidate`.

```
x <- rep(TRUE, 3)
y <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 3)

m <- length(x)
n <- length(y)
(candidate <- seq.int(length = n - m + 1L))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

i <- 1L
which(x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]) 
which(x[1] == y[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]
which(TRUE == c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))
#[1] 1 3 4 5 7 8 9

# remove 2nd, 6th and 10th from candidate
(candidate <- candidate[x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]])
#[1] 1 3 4 5 7 8 9

i <- 2L
which(x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L])
which(x[2] == y[c(2,4,5,6,8,9,10)]
which(TRUE == c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))
#[1] 2 3 5 6

# shorten to 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 6th of candidate
(candidate <- candidate[x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]])
#[1] 3 4 7 8

i <- 3L
which(x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L])
which(x[3] == y[c(5,6,9,10)]
which(TRUE == c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
#[1] 1 3

# shorten to 1st and 3rd of candidate
(candidate <- candidate[x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]])
#[1] 3 7
```

Comment: I like the function, but I don't understand the ` candidate[x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]]`  business of these lengths and indexing. It seems to do some sort of 'window matching' but I don't quite get it. Do you have an easy explanation of it by any chance?

Comment: @saQuist Yes, you're right, it does a *window matching*. See if the edit makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it all out and now I understand it. It turned out I was confused because mixed up different vectors at different stages of the algorithm. I hope you don't mind if I'll add some steps in between for others who might need them too.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringifiedSample <- paste(sample, collapse = " ")

lapply(df, function(col) {
  grepl(stringifiedSample, paste(col, collapse = " "), fixed = TRUE)
})

$test1
[1] TRUE

$test2
[1] FALSE

$test2.1
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I expected it would be possible by converting to strings, but I thought it was a nasty detour. Your solution, however, seems pretty elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
which(rowSums(mapply(function(x, y) x == y, sample, df)) == ncol(df))
```

Comment: This returns `1 5 9` in this case. What does that mean?

Comment: The rows of the data frame that much your condition

Comment: Okay, but I actually need to match column-wise. So the occurrence of the vector `sample` in every column separately, and if possible, the row of the first match.